# Regular expression for capuring entire lines that start with either '###' or '*** Entry'

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I have large files that each contain many lines, some lines are prefixed with series of characters, for example:

```
*** Entry 4 *** 05-17-2021 08:05:36
```

And

```
### Scrambled GET_DEVICE_INFO response ###
### VIEW_LOG_RADIO EnabledE(¾ç@VENT_CRIT_MANUF 8 ###
```

I would like my search to return all lines that begin with either `###` or `*** Entry`, but am seeing unexpected results.  i.e. I am seeing content returned that is outside what I intended to include.  The closest I have so far is:

```
^[(###|*** Entry)].*
```

It returns the message:

*"Reached maximum result size. Check "find_in_files_max_result_size".
176949 matches across 3552 files"*

I am looking for suggestions to either improve this attempt, or for an entirely new expression.

Note, I have included the 'Sublime Text' tag only because that happens to be the utility in which I am using because it includes regular expression searches.  Please don't exclude your idea due to this tag :)

***Edit*** to address question in comments:

Searching 14 files for "^(###|*** Entry).*$" (regex)

```
C:\tempExtract\___CR2_ISL_CharacterizationStudy\SummaryDataAnalysislogs\3304.txt:
    1  
    2: *** Entry 1 *** 05-17-2021 06:58:51
    3  *** ID: 49241341 ***
    4  *** PN: 3315185-000 ***
    .
    6  *** Conclusions-Description: ***
    7  
    8: ### Device is not enumerated ###
    9: ### Occurs after 'RelayRelayRelayRelayRelayRelay' ###
   10  
   11  
   12: *** Entry 2 *** 05-17-2021 07:00:17
   13  *** ID: 49236843 ***
   14  *** PN: 3315185-000 ***
   ..
   16  *** Conclusions-Description: ***
   17  
   18: ### Error in MTI command ###
   19  
   20  
   21: *** Entry 3 *** 05-17-2021 07:01:48
   22  *** ID: 48729163 ***
   23  *** PN: 3315185-004 ***
   ..
   25  *** Conclusions-Description: ***
```

Comment: You don't need the square brackets at all.  But it should work if you remove them (and escape the asterisks). https://regex101.com/r/4aC1d0/1

Comment: @JerryJeremiah - Thanks, will give that a try.  Can you comment on why the square brackets are not required.  (I am very new to regular expressions)

Comment: The square brackets mean "find exactly one from the list of characters inside" so `^[abc].*` means from the start of the line find exactly one of the characters a, b or c followed by zero or more other characters.  So `^[(###|*** Entry)].*` literally means from the start of the line find exactly one of the listed characters followed by more of any character - which would match almost every line in the file.

Comment: With `awk`: `awk '!/^\*\*\* Entry/ && !/^###/' file > newfile` ([demo](https://ideone.com/AU7C3u))

Comment: So, `^(###|\*\*\* Entry).*`  says from the start of the line find either `###` or `*** Entry` followed by zero or more characters - you need the backslashes because the asterisk has a special meaning.  And then it puts the part inside the parenthesis into subgroup 1 so if you don't need subgroups you can use a non-capturing version: `^(?:###|\*\*\* Entry).*`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew -  have used `awk`, but only in a UNIT shell.  I do not have that available in this environment.  I am not sure Sublime includes that as an option.

Comment: Well, now you understand why regex is always accompanied with another tag precising the environment where the regex is used. BTW, awk is very good at processing big files.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah - The expression in your last comment works better than everything else.  I had 181 matches across all 12 files.   Its good.  It also include some extra lines for the `*** Entry` :  eg.  `*** Entry 1 *** 05-20-2021 13:37:53 2 *** ID: 49320203 *** 3 *** PN: 3315185-002 *** . 5 *** Conclusions-Description: *** 6`  Would you care to enter it as an answer?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Agreed. (I am glad I included the Sublime tag.)  btw,  I used `AWK` extensively to parse through telemetry files during the start-up phases of the Sea-Launch program (back when dirt was new.)

Comment: @JerryJeremiah - your suggestion solves my problem well enough.  If you have time, please enter an answer.

Comment: @ryyker  I can fix it to be better if you can tell me what it matches that it shouldn't and why it shouldn't.  The example line you gave in your previous comment starts with `*** Entry` so I thought it should be included from the description in the question.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah - Yes, that is correct.  In comment above I include some additional lines that were also included that do not need to be...  The line beginning with `*** Entry` is good, but search also returned lines followig that:  `*** ID: 49320203 *** 3 *** PN: 3315185-002 *** . 5 *** Conclusions-Description: ***`.  Will ending at `newline` stop the search for that line?  So, the only line I want that starts with `***`, is the one that also includes `Entry` following ``***`, i.e. `*** Entry`.  These are programmatically created files, so the syntax will be consistent between segments of file

Comment: Perhaps it needs to end with `$` - I expected SublimeText to know that the regex should only include the line that matches but perhaps it is running the stuff in single line mode.  Try `^(###|\*\*\* Entry).*$` and if it works I will write an answer.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah - See edit in post above for excerpt of results using `^(###|\*\*\* Entry).*$`

Comment: @JerryJeremiah - I am being called away.  Will check this again when I return, early tomorrow probably.  Thanks.

Comment: The regex should only match lines that start with `*** Entry` and not other lines starting with `***` unless SublimeText is using single-line mode where the dot in the regex includes the newline - then it would include lots of lines.  If that is the case we need to turn off single-line mode - either there is a way to do that (a checkbox on the search form or something?) or in the regex itself.  Try `(?m-s)^(?:###|\*\*\* Entry).*$` which turns on the multi-line flag and turns off the single-line flag: https://regex101.com/r/51adk0/1

Comment: The other thing you can try is `^(###|\*\*\* Entry)[^\n]*` which replaces the dot with a negative character class `[^\n]` which means "any character except a newline" so if this works it is the right answer.  Are you sure it is separated with a newline?  If it isn't and SublimeText just shows it on separate lines then neither the `$` or `[^\n]` will work.  For example, perhaps the character is a carriage return instead of a newline?  Does SublimeText show you the control characters at the end of the lines?

Comment: Hold on,  Why are some of the lines in your edit red and some blue?  And why do the blue ones have a colon after the line number and the red ones don't?  I'm sure that is significant.  If we understood that we would know what is going on...

Comment: @JerryJeremiah - Good question, It appears that only the blue lines are matches, (and in Sublime, they are also hyperlinks to the source file line from where they were found.) the others are context surrounding the match. (As I said I am new to using regular expressions, and also new to using them in Sublime. )  So, your expression works perfectly here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The square brackets in a regex mean "find exactly one from the list of characters inside" so `^[abc].*` means "from the start of the line, find exactly one of the characters a, b or c followed by zero or more other characters". So `^[(###|*** Entry)].*` literally means "from the start of the line, find exactly one of the characters listed in the square brackets followed by more of any character" - which would match almost every line in the file.

But, `^(###|\*\*\* Entry).*` (without the square brackets) means "from the start of the line, find either `###` or `*** Entry` followed by zero or more characters" - you need the backslashes because the asterisk has a special meaning. And then it puts the part inside the parenthesis into subgroup 1 so if you don't need subgroups you can use a non-capturing version: `^(?:###|\*\*\* Entry).*`

You can see `^(?:###|\*\*\* Entry).*` in action here: https://regex101.com/r/4aC1d0/1

Comment: I've been using this all day.  It and some adaptations have worked well.  Thanks!